# Lowering memory cost of drawing in C#

Tags: c#, memory, graphics, gdi, drawimage

I'm storing an image in a Bitmap. When I resize my object my image needs to get resized as well. I have made a function for resizing my image to the required size.

I am already only calling this function when I absolutely need to resize the image, but the memory cost of me continually messig with the size of this image quickly jumps from 50 MB to over 1 GB. (This method needs to be called at every millisecond when my mouse button is held down.)

I have my `Graphics` in `using` but that seems to help little in this case.
If I call `GC.Collect(2)` on it that helps of course but it slows down the GUI extremely, and if I set it to non-blocking then it doesn't help much at all.

Is there a way to free up the memory that is not still used by the last instance of this function being called or do I need to change my code and do this another way? If there is a better way I'd appreciate some help, because it seems that either GDI is leaky or my method is very inefficient.

MY CODE:

```
public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public void createScaledImage()
{
    var cr = new c_returnGraphicSettings();
    if (getWidth() > 20 && getHeight() > 20)
    {
        scaledImage = new Bitmap(getWidth(), getHeight());
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(scaledImage))
        {
            /*
            g.InterpolationMode = cr.getIM();
            g.PixelOffsetMode = cr.getPOM();
            g.SmoothingMode = cr.getSM();
            /*--*/

            g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), scaledImage.Size), new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), image.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.Dispose();
        }

        //GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);

    }
}

public Bitmap getScaledImage()
{
    //createScaledImage();
    return scaledImage;
}

public void resizeImage()
{
    if(image != null)
    {
        createScaledImage();
    }
}
```

CODE ON THE MAIN FORM:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    //TODO: PAINT!!
    organizeImageList();
    foreach (c_ImageHolder c in Limages)
    {
        if (c != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(c.getScaledImage(), c.Position);
            ...
        }
    }
}


private void f_Screen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Limages.Sort(new intComparerDesc());
    foreach (c_ImageHolder c in Limages)
    {
        if (renhan.pointInPosition(e.Location, new Rectangle(c.Position, c.Size)))
        {
            c.select();
            selectedImage = c;
            imageDragPoint = new Point(e.X - c.Left, e.Y - c.Top);
            if (!c.isOverAnEdge(imageDragPoint) && !c.isOverACorner(imageDragPoint)) 
            { 
                resize = false; 
                cResizer = null; 
                ed = edges.none; 
                cor = corners.none; 
            }
            else 
            { 
                resize = true; 
                cResizer = c; 
                if (c.isOverAnEdge(imageDragPoint))
                { 
                    ed = c.overWhichEdge(imageDragPoint); 
                    cor = corners.none; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    cor = c.overWhichCorner(imageDragPoint); 
                    ed = edges.none; 
                } 
            }
            mdown = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    Invalidate();
}
```

[image]

---

EXPLANATION:

I'm using a class I made to store a bitmap image with some data about it's size and position, and then I use this to draw that image onto a screen that stores an instance of this class.

I'm not using controls (picturebox etc...) for this because of transparency issues.

Each instance contains a different image. I also need to be able to resize these images. For this reason I Have a second bitmap where I store the resized version of the original bitmap.

I use a different bitmap to store the resized image so that if I need to resize again, I'm not resizing the already modified image but the original one. (to retain quality)

The resizing is handled as such: 
I hold down the mouse button over the edge of the image. While I move the mouse while the button is held down every time I resize, the class generates a new image stretching the original image over the new size. Than that image is returned to the main screen which is invalidated and at paint it draws the new image onto the background of the screen.

The problem is that since I need to draw this image onto the background I cannot dispose it. I can make a copy and dispose the original but I think, that at that point I'd have the same problem.

While I am holding the mouse button down and redrawing the image constantly, the memory is spiking quickly. I can dispose after I'm done, but just resizing an image for long enough can crash the program.

I have made a smaller much more simple program demonstrating my problem as well as a short video you can find both here: [Video and link to program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViOmvNUbf6A)

There is a link to my demo program stored in dropbox in a rar file under the video.

I hope this explanation and the video/demo helps explain my problem better.

Thank you, to everyone who is trying to help!

Comment: You're leaking stuff left and right. Call `Dispose()` on old bitmaps. And `using` already calls `Dispose()` on `g`, no need to do it by hand. If your code is correct, there's no need to call `GC.Collect()` at all.

Comment: What happens with the result?  You are creating a *new* bitmap for the (apparently) smaller image, so you will have 2 total images to dispose of at some point (`image` and `scaledImage`)

Comment: why do you resize bitmap manually? on view let the control do the resizing, and when you are done with resizing (after you release mouse click), generate and store new bitmap.

Comment: @xxbbcc The second part I kinda guessed I just put it in there to try. The first part though, I'm using the same bitmap called `scaledimage` drawing on it and returning it to the function that called it. Are you saying I should use a throwaway bitmap in the middle that I use to create the image and then dispose it?

Comment: @Plutonix I have an original bitmap that holds the image I'm resizing and the resized image. I need this because if you resize the image and make it smaller then decide you need it larger instead, you'd get a messed up image, so I'm resizing the original every time.

Comment: Yeah, and at some point you move onto a new image to fiddle with.  Dispose of both of them at that time

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I resize it manually, because I don't have a control, I can't use a control because in winforms controls don't have proper background transparency and I need that so I just draw my images instead

Comment: @Plutonix Actually no, I'm working with multiple images, this is a separate class designed to hold images like an object which are then manipulated on a main screen, I can't dispose of the images as long as the user is messing with them

Comment: But when they decide to redo something a time, you need to dispose of the previous version because *that code* always creates a fresh new `scaledImage`.  We dont know how that code is used, so we have no context.  it certainly sounds like you are not disposing of anything

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not disposing of the existing bitmap images, because I need them constantly, I cannot draw an image to the screen if the image is disposed. That seems to be the lesser problem though, the problem is that while I am resizing the image, moving my mouse constantly and forcing it to redraw the image, the memory keeps raising quickly, easily reaching GB territory. Once I let go of the mouse it drops back down to managable levels, but while I'm resizing I can actually cause GDI to crash with a ˛`not enough memory` error. I'm looking to fix that problem

Comment: @WolfyD Hence, you need to dispose the scaledImage if it is not null. On the other hand, why not simply project the original image to the canvas? You seem to do it accurately when you are creating the scaledImage (giving a rectangle as a target), why not to this during the drawing? There would be no need creating the scaledImage if you use [Graphics.DrawImage-Methode: (Image, RectangleF, RectangleF, GraphicsUnit)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ktyfbs10(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method

Comment: @Icepickle #1 I probably have some problem, not understanding this, please explain how I can dispose the scaledImage when I need to use it to draw to the screen? If I knew that was possible I would have done it by now. #2 Yes that was my original method, sadly that requires a memory intensive drawing every time I paint the main screen not just when I resize an image, so it broke my program just about instantly, that is why I only call resize when I'm actually resizing not all the time while drawing.

Comment: @WolfyD Any chance you could provide  an [mcve] that demonstrates your problem? No need to give us all the code, but just to give us a general idea of what you are trying to accomplish? I am currently limited by my imagination, but it seems you are trying to create an image explorer of some kind. It could be most helpful in resolving your problem. Also, do you really need live update during resizing? It seems a bit overkill for most user scenarios

Comment: @Icepickle I will try, I gues sthe problem is that I understand my problem, I assumed others will as well. I'll edit my question and add a proper comprehensive example. Thank you

Comment: I think the right answer is as @Icepickle suggested - scale the image as you draw it - at least, while the user is resizing the image. You can generate and store a new static scaled image after the resize is complete. But don't create and throw away a bitmap for every single mouse-movement while resizing.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I started writing a reply when I realized what you meant, it took me this long to realize that I made a mistake when keeping a mechanic from the old code when I managed these images from controls. Thanks a lot for the help. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who tried to help. I finalyl realized where I went wrong.

I kept a function from my original code when I managed my images in controls.

With my new code I could have managed the resizing without writing it to a new Bitmap.

I don't know why I didn't understand that after like 5 people told me the same thing.

Again thanks.